# How to deploy ContextBroker in production?

Tags: scalability, high-availability, fiware, fiware-orion

we are analysing the FIWARE NGSI architecture to provide easy to scale and fault tolerant recipes for deployment of related enablers. Of course we plan to start from the ContextBroker case.

Our idea, but we would appreciate a feedback, since we may not be aware of full internal details of ContextBroker and implications of the way we may use it, its the following:

1. Define a compose/docker recipe that support federation of contextBroker instances (as described in the documentation here: https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user/federation/index.html)
2. Include in the recipe the configuration of a load balancer with virtual IP that balance the requests to the different private IPs of the contextBroker.
3. Explore additional configuration options on top, that could be, for example, geographical "sharding" depending on the client IP.

Of course each instance of context broker would have it's own "database" instance. An alternative, could be positioning the "synch" layer of high availability at the data base level, leveraging on the "replication" functionalities of mongo db. But I am not sure this is a good idea.

Any feedback is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the deployment (edit the question post to add a diagram will help) but if each CB instance plays the role of an independent logical node with its own context data (I guess so given that you mention federation between different CB nodes) my recomendation for a production deployment is to set up each node in High Availability (HA) way.

I mean, instead of having just one CB in each node, use an active-active CB-CB configuration, with a load balancer in front of them. Both CBs will use the same MongoDB database. In order to get HA also in the DB layer you would need to use MongoDB replica sets.